# Javascript detect a selection of browser AutoComplete value

Tags: javascript, input, autocomplete, onchange

I have a text field with an `onkeyup` event. But this event is not fired when I select a browser autoComplete value. I have added an onclick event, but it doesn't work.

I have tested many solutions posted on stackoverflow for catching the browse autocoComplete selection, but nothing has resolved this problem.

Try this simple example to see the issue (reproduced on Firefox 3.6, Chrome 10.0 and IE8):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function onkeyupInput(){
            $('#divResult').text($('#myInput').val());
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="#">
        Tape a value and send it. Then select this value with your browser AutoComplete value :<br />
        <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" onkeyup="onkeyupInput();" onclick="onkeyupInput();" value="" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    Result of onkeypress and onclick :
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    <br />
    <b>The issue : Result of onkeypress and onclick is not update when an autocomplete value of a browser is selected.</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Newer browsers support the oninput event:

```
$(function () {
  $('#myInput').on("input",function() {
    $('#divResult').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

---

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" value="" />
```

---

If you need to support older browsers, try

```
var tId = "";
function monitor() {
 $('#divResult').text($('#myInput').val());
}

$(function () {
  $('#myInput')
  .focus(function() {
      tId=setInterval(monitor,100);
  })
  .blur(function() {
      clearInterval(tId);
  });
});
```

Comment: @goby Great - glad to help and to learn something in the process

Comment: listening to input event was only half the solution for me. To allow the field to behave as if it was manually modified, I had to "setTimeout(function(){//code to override input.value with input.value},1}", else the input field would even have a different background color :-/