# jQuery listener for autocomplete selection on text field

Tags: jquery, forms, input, autocomplete, listener

I have some jQuery listeners setup which listen for form input on a `type="text"` field. However when the user selects an option from the autocomplete drop down box (i.e. a value they've entered previously which has been remembered for future use) the listeners below don't collect that value.

Here's my current code:

```
$('#text-input').on("keyup change paste", function() {
    var textInput = $(this).val();
    // do something with textInput
});
```

The above works for pasting and typing in but not when an option is selected from a drop down suggestion list.

Can anyone tell me what the listener is I need to add?

Cheers.

---

**My Solution**

Having tried using the `autocomplete` listener I found this didn't seem to work in my scenario so instead I added the following code, inspired by the accepted answer.

```
var timer = 0;
$('#text-input').on("keyup change paste", function() {
    if (timer != null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            var textInput = $(this).val();
            // do something with textInput
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The added bonus of this is that my text input is taking a URL and then uses it to load additional content into the page. By having a timeout set it means the script isn't constantly trying to load the URL whilst the user is still typing it in.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event - You can either use that plugin OR maybe look at what all events they're handling..

Comment: It does sound like interesting question hence asking you for clarity: please correct me if I am wrong: all you want if to remember the previously typed value in input box when you select a new value from the autocomplete drop down? plz lemme know, I might flick you a possible solution`:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit: I'm afraid your mistaken, I want to get the value the user selects from the autocomplete box.

Comment: @diggersworld aha okies can I post an answer and let me know if that suits you? is that cool? `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You need to add a listener on the list of suggestions (either on the entire list, [with delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or on each value in turn). Whenever a click event happens on a suggestion, you update the value in your search box.</s>

---

I've just realized that you mean the browser's default suggestions (i.e. the  `autocomplete` attribute). This answer might help: [Javascript detect a selection of browser AutoComplete value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430342/javascript-detect-a-selection-of-browser-autocomplete-value). It polls the input for values when it has focus so that even if the autocomplete does not trigger any events, the change is detected.

Comment: I'm referring to the browser's default suggestion list. Not one I've produced. Does your comment still stand?

Comment: Nope, see my update. I first thought you had some custom autocomplete solution in place.